"It has a four-person crew." vs "It has a crew of four."
"Polaris Dawn has a four-person crew." BBC - Looks like a perfect world
I didn't know I could use "four-person crew". Rather I thought we would have to say "It has a crew of four." Now that we have this structure which is easy to use, can I use the same structure to refer to other things, for example:
It is a two-person room. instead of "a room for two".
It is a one person car. instead of "a car for one."
It is three person food instead of "food for three."
What do you think? Does it work?

You can speak of a two-person tent, but hotels usually refer to a double or twin room (according to the type of bed(s) in it). Three person food is definitely not idiomatic.

You're conflating "consisting of N persons" and "designed for, suitable for N persons".

I add to what @Kate Bunting  said.

It is a double (or twin) room.

Edit
The second would sound better if phrased as It is a single-seater car.
The third would sound better if phrased as It is a three-person (set) meal.

I will echo Kate and make explicit that we hyphenate most compound adjectives if they are placed before the noun which they modify, so a single-seater (or single-seat) car, a three-person set meal.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey, for the reminder.  I've  just hyphenated single-seater.

I didn't know "set meal". Is it the same as "prix fixe"?

@Yunus, yes, it's what Google describes in its definition for: 'prix fixe
a meal consisting of several courses served at a total fixed price'.
